# How can I parse a JSON array of either strings or objects?

Tags: json, rust, serde-json

An API I hit has poorly structured JSON. Someone decided that it was a great idea to send back a list that looks like this

```
features: [
  "First one",
  "second one",
  {
    "feature": "third one",
    "hasAdditionalImpact": true
  },
  "forth one"
]
```

I've figured out a *way* to get this data into a struct but that was effectively:

```
struct MyStruct {
    SensibleData: String,
    SensibleTruthy: bool,
    features: serde_json::Value,
}
```

This doesn't help me normalize and verify the data.

Is there a good way to turn that first object into something like

```
features: [
  {
    "feature": "First one",
    "hasAdditionalImpact": false
  },
  {
    "feature": "second one",
    "hasAdditonalImpact": false
  },
  {
    "feature": "third one",
    "hasAdditionalImpact": true
  },
  {
    "feature": "forth one",
    "hasAdditionalImpact": false
  }
]
```

I saw [type_name](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/fn.type_name.html) might be usable for checking the type and doing post-processing after it's be parsed by `serde_json`, but I also saw that `type_name` is for diagnostic purposes so I'd rather not use that for this purpose.

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [How to conditionally deserialize JSON to two different variants of an enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57639162/155423); [Convert two types into a single type with Serde](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66961340/155423); [How to deserialize JSON where the types of the values are specified in another field?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54295220/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: See also [Rust serde deserializing a mixed array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57903579/155423); [Deserializing JSON array containing different types of object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64044188/155423). Really, there's quite a lot of results from casual searching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the features in your JSON have two forms; an explicit object and a simplified form where some fields are defaulted or unnamed. You can model that with an eum like this:

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum Feature {
    Simple(String),
    Explicit {
        feature: String,
        #[serde(rename = "hasAdditionalImpact")]
        has_additional_impact: bool,
    }
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3c4b0439d099faefafc78ad1c97a75f5))

The `#[serde(untagged)]` attribute means it will attempt to deserialize into each variant in order until one succeeds.

---

If the enum is going to be annoying, you can convert them all into the same struct, with default values, using `#[serde(from)]` and providing a `From` conversion:

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum FeatureSource {
    Simple(String),
    Explicit {
        feature: String,
        #[serde(rename = "hasAdditionalImpact")]
        has_additional_impact: bool,
    },
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(from = "FeatureSource")]
struct Feature {
    feature: String,
    has_additional_impact: bool,
}

impl From<FeatureSource> for Feature {
    fn from(other: FeatureSource) -> Feature {
        match other {
            FeatureSource::Simple(feature) => Feature {
                feature,
                has_additional_impact: false,
            },
            FeatureSource::Explicit {
                feature,
                has_additional_impact,
            } => Feature {
                feature,
                has_additional_impact,
            },
        }
    }
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5a8c79ee44b6238d5eb5177fe6fb6649))

`FeatureSource` is only used as an intermediate representation and converted to `Feature` before the rest of your code ever sees it.

Comment: Sorry it took me a bit to reply; thank you so much! This is awesome. The second one is perfect and I can use that to extrapolate what I need to do for the rest of this strange parsing for this project as well! I've accepted and upvoted your answer. You're great!